# How to redirect a backup file into another folder/drive while using mysqldump?

Tags: windows, mysql

I need to use mysqldump to take backups for databases. but while executing the command, it throws the error " Access Denied ".

I found that the problem is not with the MySQL. But, it is with Windows file system. I don't have enough write privileges in bin folder placed in C drive.

How to get rid of this issue ?? How can i change the backup file path ??

thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.Check your user has enough privileges to issue mysqldump on target database  
2. check that you have permission to create a file in your dumped directory,
3. check mysql error log file

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
mysqldump --host=HOST-DETAILS -u USERNAME -p DBNAME > D:\sqldump\dump1.sql
```

Comment: Thanks !! In fact, I didn't tried that. Instead I re-installed MySQL in D drive, then the problem solved ;)